# Finding all Harmonic functions on given domain

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, holomorphic-functions

let $\Omega$ be a domain in $\mathbb{C}$. find all harmonic functions $U:\Omega \to\mathbb{R}$ such that the set $$ G=\left\{z \in \Omega: \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} =0, \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} =0\right\}$$ has a limit point in $\Omega$.

how to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $u_x-iu_y$ is holomorphic in $\Omega.$

Comment: @zhw.let $f(z)=u_x - iu_y$.then $G \subset Z(f)$,where $Z(f)$ is zero set of $f$ in $\Omega$. hence $f=0$ map .which imply $u_x=u_y=0$ in whole $\Omega$. from this what we can say about $u$?

Comment: @Eklavya Come on, you know this result.

Comment: $u $ is constant on $\Omega$??

Comment: @Eklavya Correct.